# cannot import name admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am new at Django. I am trying to create basic admin panel. when I changed the urls.py file and I put url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), into patterns then it gave error like that:

```
Request Method: GET return      
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/    
Django Version: 1.4     
Exception Type: ImportError     
Exception Value:cannot import name admin    
Exception Location:/home/ulascan/Desktop/projects/purple/purple/urls.py in <module>, line 1     
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python     
Python Version: 2.7.3     
Python Path:        
['/home/ulascan/Desktop/projects/purple',    
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',    
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2'      
 ...
 ...]
```

Comment: You're trying to import `admin` module, which is not available. Use `from django.contrib import admin` instead.

Comment: Please check the `uncommented` things mention in first answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that in your `settings.py` you have `django.contrib.admin`, **uncommented** in `INSTALLED_APPS`. And also check that you have these lines in your `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```